# Where does one see logged unsubscribe events

Tags: marketing-cloud, event, logging

We are logging events in ExactTarget when people unsubscribe from our newsletters, a la

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/invokeexecute.htm

This works on one of our unsubscribe pages -- in the it is including these events in our unsub accounts -- but not another.

What I want to know is, where I can actually see the logs? The two pages have slightly different reasons, and it would be helpful to see if the page I made is even recording those events. But I don't see in the interface where to look at those things, and have struggled to find any mention of it online.

It looks like you can do it through the API potentially, but is it in the interface anywhere? (it could be that I just don't have permission for it at the moment)

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unsubscribe reason is visible in the "All Subscribers" list view. If the unsubscribe event is logged in another publication list you'll find that information by performing the following steps:

1. Go to the "All Subscribers" list and select or search for the subscriber.
2. Select the "Lists" tab
3. Select the publication list the unsubscribe event is logged on and click "Details". There you'll find the unsubscribe reason for that subscriber.